# Relação método __dir__ e método __getattribute__

Tags: python

Galera, queria tirar uma duvida:

```
class Frob(object):
...     def __init__(self, bamf):
...             self.bamf=bamf
...     def __getattribute__(self,atr):
...             return object.__getattribute__(self,'teste')
```

Quando implemento o método **getattribute** e tento fazer o seguinte:

```
frob = Frob('random')
dir(frob)
```

Eu acabo recebendo uma lista vazia, alguem sabe me explicar o porque desse comportamento, e qual a relação existente entre esses dois métodos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você executa o `dir()` ele precisa do `__class__` para poder retornar as informações do escopo do objeto. Como você reimplementou o `__getattribute__` para sempre retornar `teste`, a função não encontra `__class__`.

Você pode reimplementar o `__dir__`, mas também é possível modificar um pouco o método para retornar `teste` exceto quando o atributo solicitado for `__class__`.

```
def __getattribute__(self, atr):
    if atr == "__class__":
        return object.__getattribute__(self, atr)
    return object.__getattribute__(self, "teste")
```

Porém você vai encontrar outro problema, será retornado um erro pois não existe atributo `teste` na sua classe, então para tudo funcionar é preciso inicializá-lo.

```
    def __init__(self, bamf):
        self.bamf = bamf
        self.teste = "TESTE"
```

Segue código completo:

```
class Frob(object):
    def __init__(self, bamf):
        self.bamf = bamf
        self.teste = "TESTE"

    def __getattribute__(self, atr):
        if atr == "__class__":
            return object.__getattribute__(self, atr)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, "teste")


frob = Frob('random')
print(dir(frob))
print(frob.bamf)
```

Saída no console:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
TESTE
```

Comment: Valeu irmão, agora fez sentido pra mim!

Comment: até achei que a sua resposta estivesse errada, porque.  é bem estranho o `dir` interno usar o acesso normal , pelo `getattribute` do objeto - mas, de fato é isso mesmo que acontece. Coloquei uma outra resposta complementando o que o `__getattribute__` faz de fato.

Comment: (a propósito - isso é mais um detalhe de implementação que algo especificado na linguagem - vale a pena olhar por exemplo o que acontece no pypy (outra implementação de Python))

Answer (score 2):

Esse seu exemplo caiu em uns meandros difíceis de entender e de explicar.
E a razão disso é que você substitui o `__getattribute__` - esse é um método
muito delicado, por que ele envolve realmente *toda* a busca de atributos 
do objeto - inclusive as que são feitas internamente pelo método `__dir__`.

No entanto, ao contrário do que a outra resposta comenta,  o problema não 
é só o atributo `__class__` - a maior parte desses acessos ao `__class__` o Python 
faz internamente, em código nativo, e não passa pelo `__getattribute__`. Dentro do
`__dir__` no entanto, sim, ele usa o mecanismo do `__getattribute__` para chegar
a classe to objeto. Para ver a diferença entre os dois, em uma instância da sua classe `Frob` original faça `print (type(Frob(0)))`, e depois `print(Frob(0).__class__` - o `type` obtem o `__class__` diretamente, sem usar o mecanismo do `__getattribute__`.

Entender exatamente o que está acontecendo é complicado. O ideal é você criar o método `__getattr__` ,e  não `__getattribute__`  a não ser que saiba muito bem o que está fazendo. O `__getattr__` só é chamado quando o Python não achou um atributo em nenhum outro caminho.  (Inclusive a própria chamada ao `__getattr__` é feita dentro do `__getattribute__` original.

No caso de substituir o `__getattribute__`, o melhor é intervir o menos possível - trocar os atributos que você quer, em um "if" verficando apenas os atributos desejados, e delegar o restante dos atributos para o `__getattribute__` original -  e não o contrário.

Se colocar um `print` dentro do `__getattribute__` vai ver que ele é chamado pelo `__dir__` para obter `__class__` e `__dict__` - por que essa é a implementação normal do `dir`: ele mostra os atributos de classe, e os atributos de instância de um objeto - e os atributos de instância normais ficam armazendados dentro do `__dict__`.

Então, observe como, ao retornar `__dict__` e `__class__`  do `__getattribute__` você tem listados os atributos setados na instância:

```py
class Frob(object):
    def __init__(self, bamf):
            self.bamf=bamf
            self.teste = 5
    def __getattribute__(self,atr):
           print(atr)
           if atr in ("__class__", "__dict__"):
               return super().__getattribute__(atr)
           return object.__getattribute__(self,'teste')
```

No terminal:

```py
In [54]: print(dir(Frob(1)))                                                                                                         
__dict__
__class__
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bamf', 'teste']
```

## Resumo do mecanismo do `__getattribute__`

Se for sobre-escrever `__getattribute__` tem que fazer com cuidado - e lembrar que nesse código que é feita a busca de atributos normais do Python, que é razoavelmente complexa:

1. ele verifica primeiro se o atributo existe na classe do objeto (e faz isso usando o "type", não `obj.__class__`, que seria recursivo:

   - Se o atributo existe *na classe* ele verifica se esse atributo é um objeto que tem os métodos `__get__` e `__set__` (um "data descriptor"):

     - Se sim (mas não se tem só o `__get__` e não tem o `__set__`) - ele chama o método `__get__` do atributo, passando a instância (self) e a classe (type(self)) e *retorna* esse valor.
2. na sequência, o `__getattribute__` verifica se o objeto tem um `__dict__` (sem recursividade, usando mecanismos internos), se sim, verifica se o atributo existe nesse  `__dict__` e retorna esse valor. (o `__dict__` de um objeto tem que ser um dicionário real de Python, e se você tentar colocar uma subclasse que mude o  `__getitem__`, esse método especial vai ser ignorado)
3. O `__getattribute__` verifica se a classe do objeto tem `__slots__` e retornar o valor do slot correspondente ao nome
4. O `__getattribute__` verifica se o valor existe na classe do objeto.

   - se existir e tiver o método `__get__`, esse método é chamado, com a instância e a classe (os métodos normais de objetos são criados nesse ponto), e retorna o valor obtido.
   - senão só retorna o atributo encontrado na classe. (a busca nos valores da classe nesse item (4) e no item (1) *não* chama o método `__getattribute__` da classe (type(self)) do objeto), ela simplesmente olha o `__dict__` da classe, e prossegue, olhando o `__dict__` das super-classes (a ordem linearizada das super-classes, que fica sempre no atributo `__mro__` da classe).

     1. Se o atributo ainda não foi encontrado, se existir o método `__getattr__` ele é chamado. Se o `__getattr__` retornar um valor, ele é devolvido. Se o  `__getattr__` levantar uma exceção de `AttributeError`, o `__getattribute__` conitnua a busca nos `__getattr__` das super-classes do objeto.
     2. O `__getattribute__` levanta a exceção de `AttributeError`.

Então é isso - essa complexidade é o que faz Python no final ser tão simples e facil de usar-  por que ele faz "o que esperamos que faça", mesmo que a gente não pare pra pensar que tudo isso acontece por baixo dos panos.

E também, por conta dessa complexidade, é que inventaram o método irmão  `__getattr__`, que pode ser customizado de forma muito mais simples.